# WSO2 2.1.0 - update 14 Store exception Cannot read property "length" from null

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Using WSO2AM 2.1.0-update14 on kubernetes-apim (custom built images) I face an axception when user tries to list applications or apis in the store.

```
ERROR -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/api-listing-all/template.jag#98) {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager}
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from null (/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/api-listing-all/template.jag#98)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
```

[here is a more complete stacktrace](https://pastebin.com/VRTAvmQJ) with debug information.

As far I understood the jaggery app (Store) encounter null list so it throws a NullPointerException, however I response contains an application

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:retrieveOAuthApplicationResponse xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd">
            <ns:return xmlns:ax288="http://base.identity.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax286="http://model.api.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax284="http://api.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax282="http://keymgt.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax290="http://dto.impl.apimgt.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax291="http://util.java/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax286:OAuthApplicationInfo">
                <ax286:appOwner xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ax286:callBackURL xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ax286:clientId>iSIs0GfOf4Wq1cmRncGfmmDAU5Qa</ax286:clientId>
                <ax286:clientName xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ax286:clientSecret>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ax286:clientSecret>
                <ax286:isSaasApplication>false</ax286:isSaasApplication>
                <ax286:jsonString>{"grant_types":"refresh_token urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer password client_credentials iwa:ntlm","redirect_uris":null,"client_name":"Admin_visibility test_PRODUCTION"}</ax286:jsonString>
            </ns:return>
        </ns:retrieveOAuthApplicationResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope> {httpclient.wire.content}
```

AS well the database definitely contains a default application and another newely created application (AM_APPLICATION table)

Note: we are using templates to configure the deployment , are there any significant changes from the base version 2.1.0? (updated version is used to support application group sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a new database redeploy was needed (the schema is different from base version 2.1.0) and I didn't find any utility or script to upgrade :/